# MXNet: nn.Activation vs nd.relu?

Tags: python-3.x, mxnet

I am new to MXNet (I am using it in Python3)

Their tutorial series encourages you define your own [`gluon` blocks](http://gluon.mxnet.io/chapter03_deep-neural-networks/plumbing.html).

So lets say this is your block (a common convolution structure):

```
class CNN1D(mx.gluon.Block):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CNN1D, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.name_scope():
            self.cnn = mx.gluon.nn.Conv1D(10, 1)
            self.bn = mx.gluon.nn.BatchNorm()
            self.ramp = mx.gluon.nn.Activation(activation='relu')

    def forward(self, x):
        x = mx.nd.relu(self.cnn(x))
        x = mx.nd.relu(self.bn(x))
        x = mx.nd.relu(self.ramp(x))
        return x
```

This is mirror the structure of their example.
What is the difference of `mx.nd.relu` vs `mx.gluon.nn.Activation`?

Should it be

```
x = self.ramp(x)
```

instead of

```
x = mx.nd.relu(self.ramp(x))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that

```
mx.gluon.nn.Activation(activation=<act>)
```

is a wrapper for calling a host of the underlying activations from the `NDArray` module.

Thus - in principle - it does not matter if in the forward definition one uses

```
x = self.ramp(x)
```

or

```
x = mx.nd.relu(x)
```

or

```
x = mx.nd.relu(self.ramp(x))
```

as relu is simply taking the max of 0 and the passed value (so multiple applications will not affect the value any more than a single call besides from a slight runtime duration increase).

Thus in *this* case it doesnt really matter. Of course with other activation functions stacking multiple calls might have an impact.

In MXNets documentation they use `nd.relu` in the forward definition when defining `gluon.Block`s. This might carry slightly less overhead than using `mx.gluon.nn.Activation(activation='relu')`.

Flavor-wise the `gluon` module is meant to be the high level abstraction. Therefore I am of the opinion that when defining a block one should use 
`ramp = mx.gluon.nn.Activation(activation=<act>)` instead of `nd.<act>(x)` and then call `self.ramp(x)` in the forward definition.

However given that at this point all custom `Block` tutorials / documentation stick to `relu` activation, whether or not this will have lasting consequences is yet to be seen.

All together the use of `mx.gluon.nn.Activation` seems to be a way to call activation functions from the `NDArray` module from the `Gluon` module.

Answer (score 1):

[mx.gluon.nn.Activation](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/gluon.html#mxnet.gluon.nn.Activation) wraps around [mx.ndarray.Activation](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/ndarray.html#mxnet.ndarray.Activation), see [Gluon source code](https://github.com/lupesko/incubator-mxnet/blob/master/python/mxnet/gluon/nn/basic_layers.py#L223).

However, when using Gluon to build a neural net, it is recommended that you use the Gluon API and not branch off to use the lower level MXNet API arbitrarily - which may have issues as Gluon evolves and potentially change (e.g. stop using mx.nd under the hood).